# Set DropDownList Selected Value in GridView EditItemTemplate in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edititemtemplate

I need populate dropdownlist selected value getting from database in gridview edititemtemplate in asp.net using c#.

I can't do it because when edit the gridview edititemtemplate in the dropdown lists the values of default are selected and not those registered in the database.

[image]

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView g2 = (GridView)sender;
    g2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    GridViewRow gvCustomerRow = g2.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int customerId = (int)gvProducts.DataKeys[gvCustomerRow.RowIndex].Value;

    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM `doTable` ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE sID IN ('{0}') ", customerId);

    g2.DataSource = GetData(sql);
    g2.DataBind();

    DateTime dateofBirth = new DateTime();
    ddlMonth.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(a => new
    {
        MonthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(a),
        MonthNumber = a
    });
    ddlMonth.DataBind();

    DropDownList ddlYear = (DropDownList)(g2.Rows[g2.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlYear"));
    ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 0, 12).Reverse();
    ddlYear.DataBind();
    ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("0001", "0001"));

    ddlday.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Day.ToString();
    ddlMonth.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Month.ToString();
    ddlYear.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Year.ToString();

    ddlday.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, 
        Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)));
    ddlday.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do it in the aspx page. Can you show your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem :

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView g2 = (GridView)sender;
    g2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    GridViewRow gvCustomerRow = g2.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int customerId = (int)gvProducts.DataKeys[gvCustomerRow.RowIndex].Value;

    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    DateTime dateofBirth = new DateTime();

    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM `doTable` ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE sID IN ('{0}') ", customerId);

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (OdbcDataAdapter adapt =
                new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapt.Fill(dts);
                if (dts.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    g2.DataSource = dts;
                    g2.DataBind();

                    DataRow row = dts.Rows[0];

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["DateValuefromDB"].ToString()))
                    {
                        ddlMonth.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(a => new
                        {
                            MonthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(a),
                            MonthNumber = a
                        });
                        ddlMonth.DataBind();
                        DropDownList ddlYear = (DropDownList)(g2.Rows[g2.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlYear"));
                        ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 0, 12).Reverse();
                        ddlYear.DataBind();
                        ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("0001", "0001"));
                        ddlday.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)));
                        ddlday.DataBind();

                        ddlday.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Day.ToString();
                        ddlMonth.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Month.ToString();
                        ddlYear.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Year.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlMonth.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(a => new
                        {
                            MonthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(a),
                            MonthNumber = a
                        });
                        ddlMonth.DataBind();
                        DropDownList ddlYear = (DropDownList)(g2.Rows[g2.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlYear"));
                        ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 0, 12).Reverse();
                        ddlYear.DataBind();
                        ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("0001", "0001"));
                        ddlday.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)));
                        ddlday.DataBind();

                        ddlday.SelectedValue = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateValuefromDB"]).Day.ToString();
                        ddlMonth.SelectedValue = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateValuefromDB"]).Month.ToString();
                        ddlYear.SelectedValue = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateValuefromDB"]).Year.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a datasource on the page that selects the list of items for the dropdown list. Then bind the datasource to the ddl. Something like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditCompany" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="odsCompany"                         // <-- data source.
        DataTextField="CompanyName"
        DataValueField="CompanyID"
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'>         // <-- select here.
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so will post as an answer.

"... values of default are selected and not those registered in the database", because you set drop-downs in edit template to "default values":

```
    ...
    DateTime dateofBirth = new DateTime();
    ...
    ddlday.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Day.ToString();
    ddlMonth.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Month.ToString();
    ddlYear.SelectedValue = dateofBirth.Year.ToString();
    ...
```

shouldn't you set value **dateofBirth** from the database?

and for ddlYear, I think it's better to

```
    ddlYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 0, 12).Reverse().Select(x => x.ToString()).Append("0001")
```